# How to get Alt tag for Wordpress NgGallery Image

Tags: html, wordpress, nextgen-gallery

I just developed a wordpress website with ng-gallery plugin.
I want get image alt tag and add new title attribute to image tag.
Here is my code..

```
<div id="ngg-slideshow-1-6-1" class="ngg-slideshow" style="height:515px;width:576px;">

<img src="http://www.sweetpassion.com.au/wp-content/gallery/homepage/sydney-royal-easter-show-2014-master-class-competition.jpg" style="height: 515px; width: 386px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; z-index: 10; opacity: 0;">
```

I added alt and description in ng-gallery back end.But the alt attribute not showing in the home page.

Currently showing only **src** & **Style** Attributes.

How can I add **Alt and Title** attributes to above code.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nextgen gallery allows you to create custom templates.

1.In you active theme, create folder called : nggallery

2.Copy `gallery.php` from: `/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/ngglegacy/view`  to the nggallery folder you created in step 1

3.Now in nggallery folder rename `gallery.php` to `gallery-mytemplate.php` and modify it as required so that it displays the alt text and the attributes.

4.Use the following shortcode which tells Nextgen Gallery to display the gallery using your custom template and not the default one `[nggallery id=1 template=mytemplate]`